# CSCore & Unity: How to input Microphone Data (Sample Source) into Audio Source in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cscore

Im having troubles figuring out how to send microphone data into unity's audiosource. Doing it mostly for the better latency. Unity's native "Microphone..." solution takes almost a second to get through.

```
if (selected_device == null)
            {
                using (var deviceEnumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator())
                using (var deviceCollection = deviceEnumerator.EnumAudioEndpoints(DataFlow.Capture, DeviceState.Active))
                {
                    selected_device = deviceCollection[0];
                    Debug.Log("Got Device!: " + selected_device.FriendlyName);
                }
            }

            m_SoundKeeper = new WasapiCapture();
            m_SoundKeeper.Device = selected_device;
            m_SoundKeeper.Initialize();
            
            soundInSource = new SoundInSource(m_SoundKeeper);
```

With this im starting the objects, getting the mic, everything is fine here.

This one is in the update method of Unity:

```
if (!isRecordingStarted)
            {
                m_SoundKeeper.Start();
                isRecordingStarted = true;
            }

            Debug.Log("Mic Data available");

            ISampleSource convertSoundSource = soundInSource.ToSampleSource();
            convertSoundSource.Read(_microphoneBuffer, 0, _microphoneBuffer.Length);

            AudioClip audioClip = AudioClip.Create("bruhhhh", _microphoneBuffer.Length, 1, 48000, false);
            audioClip.SetData(_microphoneBuffer, 0);
            _audioSource.clip = audioClip;
            _audioSource.Play();
```

I get like a second of very distorted silent sound and then it throws errors [object reference bla bla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7uAI.png)
I think it might be because im trying to read data that is not existing yet.

I am very confused at what im doing wrong and would love some advice!

I also am using a bit modified [Caress.Unity](https://github.com/tkmn0/Caress.Unity/blob/master/Assets/Caress/_Examples/Scripts/MicrophoneRecorder.cs) because since im trying to create a multiplayer, I have to send the byte array after encoding, but its a whole another topic.